# How to stop a timer after a function has been called

Tags: timer, swift4

I have a timer and a function. I want to invalidate the timer after the function has been completed. How would I go about this? the function is called showButton()

Comment: Show.Your.Code.

Comment: *"I want to invalidate the timer"* - so it seems you already know how to stop a time (call `invalidate`). So what is your exact question? Show your relevant code and clear explain what issue you are having trying to invalidate the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare a timer variable globally to your class. Then initialize the timer when required and invalidate it when your `showButton()` function is called.

This is a small example.

```
class timerViewController: UIViewController {

     var timer: Timer!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         print("Starting Timer")
         timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerCompleted), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
     }

     @objc func timerCompleted(sender: Timer!){
         print("Timer Completed")
     }

     func showButton(){
         timer.invalidate()
     }
}
```